# ImportRow from List(Of TableRow) into new Dataset

Tags: dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

ImportRow isn't working.

I realize this subject has been covered a hundred times over, but none of the previous answers on google seem to touch on my situation.

I have a DataTable named `MessageRecords`.  Within it, I have a Table named `Messages`.  Within THAT, I have Rows named `MessagesRow`.

In one particular function named `CombineRows()`, I have the following code:

```
Private Sub CombineRows()
    Dim dtsMessage As New MessageRecords
    Dim MsgList As List(Of MessageRecords.MessagesRow)) = GetMessages()

    For Each Msg In MsgList
        dtsMessage.Messages.ImportRow(Msg)
        . . . 'Do More
    Next
    . . . 'Do More
End Sub
```

I have also tried `dtsMessage.Messages.Rows.Add(Msg)` and `dtsMessage.Messages.AddMessagesRow(Msg)`, but that gives me the `ArgumentException`: "This row already belongs to another table."

I have also tried adding `dtsMessage.Messages.AcceptChanges()` and `dtsMessage.AcceptChanges()`, but they don't have any effect.

Also to note: If I breakpoint at `dtsMessage.Messages.ImportRow(Msg)`, I can "Watch" 'Msg' it and it is a legitimate `MessagesRow` with all of my expected information.

But when I step over to the next line in the `For Each`, `dtsMessage.Messages.Rows.Count` is still Zero.  There is no error.

My previous *working* code built the `MessageRows` in the same function (the function was like 200 lines), and built each `MessageRow` as a new `dtsMessage.Messages.NewMessagesRow()`.  So `AddMessagesRow` worked fine.  But in moving to Single-Responsibility methods for Unit Testing, I put the code that built the message rows into the GetMessages() function.  It's more complicated than I made it look, or I would have included it in the loop.

So now that the list of rows isn't associated to the table, I can't `Add`.  Supposedly `ImportRow` is supposed to do the job here, but literally nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here lay in the fact that I was creating the `List(Of MessageRow)` in a different function.  There is **Technically** no such thing as a TableRow without a DataTable.  Except that as you see in my Not-Erroring code, you can have a `List(Of MessageRow)`.

But what was happening behind the scenes, which I'd consider a flaw in the .NET Framework, is that each `MessageRow` TableRow was being created as part of it's own singular `MessageRecords` DataSet, within it's own singular `Messages` table.

So in the GetMessages() Function, I essentially had this pseudocode:

```
Dim lstMessages As New List(of MessageRow)
For Each Item In QueryResults
    Dim dtt As New MessageRecords
    Dim dr As MessageRecords.MessageRow = dtt.Messages.NewMessageRow
    . . . 'Do Stuff
    lstMessages.Add(dr)
Next
Return lstMessages
```

But when the `List(Of MessageRow)` arrived back to my calling method, the Rows were Orphaned from their original `dtt` tables.

So even though, for some reason, I could access and "Watch" each of the Rows, and they were legitimately there... the fact that their original parent Datasets/DataTables were now missing, the .NET Framework (for some reason) didn't know how to either Error, or ImportRow... so just nothing happened at all.

My Solution was to change my List to `List(Of MessageRecords)` Datasets, then in my main `CombineRows()` Function, I change my loop like so:

```
Private Sub CombineRows()
    Dim dtsMessage As New MessageRecords
    Dim MsgList As List(Of MessageRecords)) = GetMessages()

    For Each MsgDataset In MsgList
        dtsMessage.Messages.ImportRow(MsgDataset.Tables(0).Rows(0))
        . . . 'Do More
    Next
    . . . 'Do More
End Sub
```

And now I don't have orphaned Rows, and ImportRow works.